# How can I make "flutter drive" fail on a RenderFlex overflow exception?

Tags: testing, flutter

I have a flutter drive integration test that will run tests on various devices as part of a CI build. Flutter drive only logs the exception in the output, but does not fail the test. Is there some way to force the test to fail when the rendering engine throws this Renderflex overflow exception?

```
$ flutter drive test_driver/app.dart

I/flutter (20477): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (20477): The following assertion was thrown during layout:
I/flutter (20477): A RenderFlex overflowed by 1.00 pixels on the bottom.
...
I/flutter (20477): ◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
I/flutter (20477): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
00:25 +4: MyTestDriver App (tearDownAll)
00:25 +4: All tests passed!
```

This exception is not propagated within the application either, so neither the app nor the "flutter drive" integration tests seem to have obvious access to it.

All searches turn up questions about how to fix the problem, but none about how to test for and detect it as part of an integration test in a CI build.

Ideally, the test would return non-zero and would let the CI system fail a commit that introduces a new rendering bug.

Comment: Can you post code block that you have tried yet

Comment: Any test that generates an overflow. Make a widget that will not render due to clipping to the parent or the device.

Answer (score 1):

After digging through the source code for flutter and dart, it seems that this is exceedingly difficult to surface to a running integration test, as user code may not even be on the stack when the problem is detected.

For anyone hoping to work around this with at least some hope of catching the problem as part of a CI build, this hack may work for your project.

The `flutter drive` script itself (in my case, change as you like, and of course, change test_driver/app.dart to whatever you have written for your tests):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TEST_COMMAND_LINE="flutter drive test_driver/app.dart"
TEST_COMMAND_LOG="build/flutter_drive.log"

# Just in case other tasks have not already created this
mkdir -p build

${TEST_COMMAND_LINE} | tee ${TEST_COMMAND_LOG}

if [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} != 0 ]; then
    echo "${TEST_COMMAND_LINE} failed. See ${TEST_COMMAND_LOG} for details"
    exit 1
fi
```

And the post-test scan of the log:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Add any errors logged by "flutter drive" here. If the text is found
# in the flutter drive output, this command will return non-zero. 
declare -a ERROR_EXPRESSIONS=(
    "EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY"
)

TEST_COMMAND_LOG="build/flutter_drive.log"

for errorExpression in "${ERROR_EXPRESSIONS[@]}"
do
    EXCEPTION_COUNT=`grep "${errorExpression}" ${TEST_COMMAND_LOG} | wc -l`
    if [ ${EXCEPTION_COUNT} != 0 ]; then
        echo "ERROR: Error expression ${errorExpression} was found in ${TEST_COMMAND_LOG}"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

This is the least elegant way to get the job done. Ideally, flutter drive would have some query to check the last exception thrown (as the widget test system does with `flutter test` and the driver), perhaps even integrated with the driver itself as a command line option so that any uncaught exceptions fail the integration test.

This may be helpful to someone else facing the same problem, but there must surely be a better way. This feels like such a project-specific hack for something that should be integral to testing with Flutter and Dart. There must be a more obvious and general way to do the same thing.

This solves my own problem, specifically, but it would be fantastic if someone more knowledgeable could share with the rest of us how to do it correctly! :)

Answer (score 0):

as simple as that:

`await driver.waitFor(find.text('NONE EXISTENT TEXT TO FAIL THE TEST'));`

ha, just saw that question is about RenderFlex, not sure if it will work, but you get the gist, will leave this answer for people like me who want to fail just any test.